# Prevent user from clicking twice on Facebook and Google sign in button

Tags: android, facebook, google-signin

I added Facebook and Google sign in in my app using:

```
private LoginButton facebook; //package com.facebook.login.widget;
private SignInButton googleSignIn; //package com.google.android.gms.common;
```

Both buttons work, I would like to prevent the users from clicking the buttons multiple times (every time it's being clicked another request is being sent):

Both cases are handled in the Google and Facebook API as follows:

1. In the Google sign in, there is a list of Google accounts of the device and once pressed I can not catch that event to disable the button once the user chose his account
2. In the Facebook sign in, it is handled by a callback registered in the Facebook package (which I don't access to) and I also can not disable the button once clicked.

Edit:
Facebook code:

```
private void ActivateFacebook() {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        facebook = (LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fb);
        ((LoginButton) facebook).setReadPermissions("email");
        ((LoginButton) facebook).setFragment(this);

        ((LoginButton) facebook).registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                onFacebookLogin(loginResult);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

What is the best practice in achieving this?
Thanks!

Comment: you cannot know when the Google button is pressed? what does the Google button do that doesn't block the UI? does it not show some dialog fragment?

Comment: dont u have an onclick listener for the button? disable the button, and then enable it when done.

Comment: I am using the google Intent. i can not access google code
 Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 101 ); @DroiDev i cant setEnable(false) but i dont have access to the code when it happens

Comment: are u looking to disable the button the user clicks to signin to google, the the buttons when choosing an account? can u show some more code? the only way ive implemented google signin is by using a global button.

Comment: @DroiDev i followed the official google tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in
My Code is similar to the one in the link above

Comment: well, that sure looks like an onclick handler. look at the 'Start the sign in flow' section. There is an onClick method...

Comment: yep, it opens small google intent with the user choise. i need to catch the listener when the user select account

Comment: i will also bet that the Google SignInButton extends a button. so you should be able to disable it...

Comment: Yes I can disable it, i am doing it, but it is an async task, it disables my button after 1-2 seconds, I want to disable it right away

Comment: you should be disabling it within the swtich/case statement. as soon as the user clicks the button, that will disable it. there is no async task there. AGAIN, you need to show more code. now u are saying you are disabling it... but u have no code to show that. im down voting.

Comment: @DroiDev I posted my code a few coments back, its:
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 101 );
p.s: I dont think downvoting me because i didnt post my code is fair. I just asked for guidance.

Comment: where did you disable the button? this is just an intent....

Comment: @DroiDev I used another implementation now, It works well. Do you know about facebook? This is the only way to implement facebook according to their tutorial (I updated my code above)

Comment: where do u run this function?

Comment: onViewCreated(); (this is a fragment)

Comment: so when a fragment is shown, this runs? im pulling teeth here. why is your code so secret?

Comment: I managed! :) i am disabling the buttons as soon as i click and it opens the google facebook inent (to which i dont have access) but I have 2 options: 1. user back to app so it goes to onResume() or 2. succesful login than it goes to the okhttp response, (Would appriciate voe up again haha) but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting an intent for the result, you can wrap the call in a conditional block, such as:

```
boolean requestSent = false;

if(!requestSent) {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();     
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 101 );
    requestSent = true;
} else {
    //show a message
}
```

Comment: My goal is to catch the moment the user choose the user in the google intent, this code is not appropriate for this